# open form from another form recieve error c#

Tags: c#, forms, error-handling

so what i am trying to do is create one main form then it will have different buttons which will take you to 4 different forms. it was working before and now it doesn't work. for example i will have a main form which will take you to pickup form, delivery form and list form etc.
so each form i write code e.g. in main form i wrote

```
private PickupForm pickupform = new PickupForm();
private DeliveryForm deliveryform = new DeliveryForm();
```

and for the `pickupform` and `deliveryform` i will write

```
private MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
```

but i seem to get error when i try to execute.
and this is the message that will show

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in coursework2.exe

and strangely when i change the order of the first two line showed earlier, the error will just occurred which ever the line come first.

so this is the all the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace coursework2
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private DeliveryForm deliveryform = new DeliveryForm();
        private PickupForm pickupform = new PickupForm();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNpickup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pickupform.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnNdelivery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            deliveryform.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an endless loop.  (until you get the stack overflow)

You create a new instance of DeliveryForm every time you create MainForm. Then create a new instance of MainForm in DeliveryForm. Then ...

If you need a reference to the main form from within DeliveryForm, set it as a property.  (And initialize it to null)

In PickupForm:

```
private MainForm mainform = null;

public MainForm ParentForm
{
    get { return mainform; }
    set { mainform = value; }
}
```

In MainForm:

```
private void btnNdelivery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   deliveryForm.ParentForm = this;
   deliveryform.ShowDialog();
   this.Close();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. now that i can navigate from mainform to different form.. but i found problem when i am trying to use the return button from pickup form and navigate back to the mainform

Comment: Remove the this.Close() after the ShowDialog() call.